# Remote Mysql IP access

Tags: mysql, apache, cpanel

I wish to grant permissions to various users for my databases using a .php script

But it seems that GRANT command is denied when accessed via PHPMYADMIN or a .php file

Is there a way out to achive this?

Comment: Is the `GRANT` command denied when coming from PHP, or is it denied for the user through which the PHP code is connecting to the database?  (Note: This is _not_ an endorsement to use `root` from your PHP code.)

Comment: its denied when coming from PHP

Comment: Is there a specific error message?  I have serious doubts MySQL knows or cares that the command is coming from PHP.

Comment: can this be done using php's exec() function, directly running a mysql command as in a shell?

Comment: You need to either MySQL's root user or a user who has GRANT privileges to connect to MySQL server from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have some kind of rights to do that, This is how you can check them:

```
show grants for 'youruser'@'localhost';
```

If you cannot find anything like `WITH GRANT OPTION` it is very likely that you cannot do that. It's not a limitation of PHP.

More on the `GRANT` command: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: `SHOW GRANTS` is a SQL query, use `mysql_query` (or PDO's equivalent)