# Execute the following via php's exec() command

Tags: php, mysql

```
exec('mysql --execute "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'122.169.XXX.XX' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'"');
```

But it gives out a error!!

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
```

The formatting should be preserved, as it needs to be the same way as its execute in the shell

Comment: Take a look at your string. You can use code colorization to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Event the stackoverflow markdown points your error.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a followup to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911916/remote-mysql-ip-access. If you are on a shared host (standard website host), this will not work! Open a question with what you actually want to achieve and let people tell you the right way to achieve that. This bit-for-bit question asking is not gonna help.

Comment: @Chronial, yes, wanting to do the same function of add a new IP in Remote mysql in Cpanel via .php file

Comment: Is that your server, or is it a shared hoster?

Comment: @its a dedicated one, was able to add a IP to my allow list in CSF via .php, and now allowing it under "Remote Hosts" in Cpanel is the 2nd..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape the `'`:

```
exec('mysql --execute "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO \'user\'@\'122.169.XXX.XX\' IDENTIFIED BY \'password\'"');
```

Comment: Uh, could be either of our answers, depending on what is actually intended. +1!

Answer (score 1):

You are starting your php string with a single quote. in the middle of your query, you are stopping it with single quotes. you need to escape them.

`exec('mysql --execute "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO \'user<'@<'122.169.XXX.XX<' IDENTIFIED BY \'password\'"');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.` to concatenate Strings.

The line should read:

```
exec('mysql --execute " GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO ' . user. '@ 122.169.XXX.XX  IDENTIFIED BY ' . password . '"');
```

Comment: You forgot the dollar signs if `user` and `password` should be variables!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your string:

```
exec('mysql --execute "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO \'user\'@\'122.169.XXX.XX\' IDENTIFIED BY \'password\'"');
```

For more information, read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your string:

Escaped:

```
exec('mysql --execute "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO \'user\'@\'122.169.XXX.XX\' IDENTIFIED BY \'password\'"');
```